# Преобразование адресов

Tags: x86

Как происходит преобразование адресов?

```
Virtual -> Linear -> Physical
```

Comment: Читайте мануал на процессор, ключевые слова `cr3`.

Comment: Например тут (кратко) http://www.realcoding.net/articles/organizatsiya-pamyati-v-zashchishchennom-rezhime-raboty-protsessora.html

Comment: Вопрос может быть общим, тогда схемы выше вам хватит. Есть два практических подхода - прямой ассемблерный или си с ассемблерными вставками, который работает только если ос нет как таковой. Любая современная ОС этот метод блокирует. Но линейный адрес нужен для DMA или некоторых других вещей (при написании драйверов например), тогда для каждой конкретной ОС существуют функции резервирования физической памяти, а так же преобразования адреса туда и назад. Уточните что вы хотите, какая конечная цель, где вы хотите это применить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physical - физический адрес. Адреса идут как есть.  Знание адреса в физической памяти нужно для DMA, или для записи непостредственно в память некоторых устройств (видеокарта например), также знание физического адреса нужно для диспечера памяти.

Linear - линейный адрес. это промежуточная часть преобразования виртуального адреса в физический. Через GDT таблицу и селектор (виртуального адреса) из таблицы GDT прибавляется "базовый адрес" к смещению - так получается линейный адрес. Затем из линейного адреса, через двойную таблицу размещения вычисляется физический адрес. Иногда виртуальный адрес путают с линейным, т.к. селекторы SS=DS=ES как правило одинаковы, что упрощает написание програм (создаётся впечатления что все адреса линейны и находятся на одном месте).

Virtual  - виртуальный адрес состоящий из селектор:смещение, который пересчитывается в линейный, а затем в физический.

Ссылки

http://www.realcoding.net/articles/organizatsiya-pamyati-v-zashchishchennom-rezhime-raboty-protsessora.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202669/linear-address-and-physical-address

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]